# Correct typing for JWT signature using express and jsonwebtoken

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jwt

I have this as my code:

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { JWT_EXPIRY, JWT_SECRET } from '../../config';

interface UserParams {
  username: string,
  password: string
}

interface ReqWithUserParams extends Request {
  user: UserParams
}

const createAuthToken = (user: UserParams): string => {
  return jwt.sign({ user }, JWT_SECRET, {
    subject: user?.username,
    expiresIn: JWT_EXPIRY,
    algorithm: 'HS256'
  });
};

export const login = (req: ReqWithUserParams, res: Response) => {
  const authToken = req.user && createAuthToken(req.user);
  if (authToken) {
    res.json({ authToken });
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
  }
};

export const refresh = (req: ReqWithUserParams, res: Response) => {
  const authToken = req.user && createAuthToken(req.user);
  if (authToken) {
    res.json({ authToken });
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
  }
};
```

There are no type errors in VSCode, but when I go to run it, I get the following error:

```
The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(req: ReqWithUserParams, res: Response) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
      Type '(req: ReqWithUserParams, res: Response) => void' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
        Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.
          Type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>' is not assignable to type 'ReqWithUserParams'.     
            Types of property 'user' are incompatible.
              Type 'User | undefined' is not assignable to type 'UserParams'.
                Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'UserParams'.
```

How can I fix this, and why is this happening?  I assumed extending Request would allow it to be assignable as type of `ParamsDictionary` just looks to be `{ [key:string]: any }`

Answer (score 0):

I was looking in the wrong file.  As it turns out, this was tracing back to to a different function, which I corrected and then was able to get rid of the error. Leaving this up in case someone else experiences this.  Just make sure you do not overlook the file path like I did!